# Release com Report não executa em outros PCs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, relatório, release, dataset

TableCriei um WinForm que contém `Reports` que buscam dados em um objeto `DataSet` (o qual é populado programaticamente utilizando uma fonte SQL Server).

O `release` fica armazenado no servidor e pode ser acessado por máquinas clientes. O problema é o que executável só roda no me PC. Nos outros é gerado um erro do tipo:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

Os arquivos de relatório `rdlc` e o objeto DataSet `xsd` estão configurados com `build action` como `Embedded Resource`.

Acredito ser a referência à algum desses objetos que está configurado errado, mas não consigo encontrar onde.

Me ajudem, por favor?

**Vale lembrar que a exceção descrita acima é gerada no relatório de erros do windows na execução do sistema nos PCs clientes, não no debug**

Segue o código que popula os dados à partir de um DataTable `dtComissoes`:

```
ds = new dsComissoes();
dsTableComissoes = ds.Tables["dtComissoes"];
foreach (DataRow row in dtComissoes.Rows)
{
    int i = dsTableComissoes.Rows.Count;
    dsTableComissoes.Rows.Add();
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["CodConta"] = row["CodConta"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["Descricao"] = row["Descricao"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["NumOrdem"] = row["NumOrdem"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["Cliente"] = row["Cliente"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["NF"] = row["NF"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["Item"] = row["Item"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["CondPagto"] = row["CondPagto"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["Titulos"] = row["Titulos"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["Parcela"] = row["Parcela"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["ValorItem"] = row["ValorItem"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["Comissao"] = row["Comissao"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["PTN"] = row["PTN"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["Valor"] = row["Valor"];
    dsTableComissoes.Rows[i]["Linha"] = row["Linha"];
}
```

E o código passado para gerar o relatório:

```
dtComissoesBindingSource.DataSource = dtComissoes;
            rpvComissoes.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("DataInicial", DataInicio.ToString()));
            rpvComissoes.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("DataFinal", DataFim.ToString()));
            rpvComissoes.LocalReport.Refresh();
            rpvComissoes.RefreshReport();
            rpvComissoes.Refresh();
```

Comment: CrystalReports?

Comment: Utilizo o Report do Visual Studio mesmo. Acho CrystalReports lento demais para carregar.

Comment: Posta o código onde tu "carrega" esse report para jogar os dados pra ele.

Comment: Postado @JéfersonBueno

Comment: Geralmente uso os ´RDLC´ como ´Content´. Porém se o pc que estiver executando o APP não possuir instalado o SQL Server e as Dlls de reporting pode ocorrer um erro. A solução que encontrei foi enviar as Dlls do Sql server e de reporting junto com as minhas Dlls

Comment: Na verdade eu queria ver o código que passa o `DataTable` para o Report hehe

Comment: Quais são as DLLs necessárias @RichardDias?

Comment: As DLLs que estão como referência no teu projeto que são relacionadas à geração de relatórios e ao SQL server. Agora não vou conseguir nomear cada uma delas especificamente, porém é um caminho para você seguir e possivelmente solucionar o seu problema

Answer (score 0):

Solucionei o problema instalando dois Packages do NuGet:

```
Microsoft Report Viewer
Microsoft.Sql.Server.Types
```

Achei melhor que apenas copiar os Dlls.
Obrigado ao @Richard Dias que me mostrou o caminhos das pedras.